# Prevent UITableView from scrolling when section header view is dragged

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a super-tall (220pt) section header on a table view that shows in app purchase information. When the user drags on the section header, the rows below scroll accordingly. It makes sense with a regular table view but in this case, the behaviour is weird.

Is there any way to prevent this happening? I've tried setting the view to `exclusiveTouch = YES` and even disabled `userInteraction` but the tableview insists on scrolling.

Comment: When you set userInteraction to NO the touch is catch by the view below it, you need to catch the touch and do nothing.
I have some ideas but I'm not sure what will work with tableView, I need to check it before I can give you a good answer.

Comment: By the way, Y not to put a regular view and smaller tableView?

Comment: I'd considered doing that but thought it would get complicated with Auto Layout, because the view needed to sometimes be hidden. In fact with an  IBOutlet on its height, it was quite straightforward and works great. No scrolling problems!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried overriding beganTouches etc but they still got passed to the table view, so in the end I abandoned using section header view and inserted the view above the table view. The view had a fixed 220pt height set in the storyboard and an NSLayoutConstraint as IBOutlet so its height could be set to 0 when the view was to be hidden.